# Using ' in html. (can't, children's, ect..)

Tags: html, web, ascii

I'm writing a website using HTML; How do i use character ' for words? 
When I try it ruins all the code which follows.

Such as - `<h3 class "heading h-03">Children's play</h3>`

however `'s play</h3>'` and everything after all goes blue

Thanks x

Comment: Please provide an example of your code.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt think it required an example.. I'll stick it as an edit

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, it's best to use codes. For example:

& = `&amp;`

Similarly, you can use `&#39;` for '

See [ASCII HTML Codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)